# PIC PWM and the use of PostScaler

Tags: pic, pwm

I'm working on a project with an [SG90](http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/pcheung/teaching/DE1_EE/stores/sg90_datasheet.pdf) servomotor, that requires the use of PWM. However the motor works with PWM frequency of 50 Hz (20 ms period), and in my [PIC16F690](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40001262F.pdf), when I try to calculate a value for the *PR2* register (per [page 129](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40001262F.pdf#page=129)), I always get a value above 255, until I reduce the F<sub>osc</sub> to less than 1 MHz, and also use a prescaler of 16.

So the question is: **is possible to use post-scaler to achieve my desired results?**

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately the PWM peripheral won't do what you want because it can't run that slow. Next best option is to use the Compare mode instead and use an interrupt service routine to handle the PWM duty.

Configure TIMER1 to run at, say, 1MHz by using the Fosc/4 clock source and the appropriate pre-scaler. Then set the PWM module to Compare mode and configure it to toggle the CCP1 output. Set the CCPR1 to the number of microseconds in your PWM "on" period. Eg. for 75% duty at 50Hz, set CCPR1 to 15000. Also enable the CCP1IF interrupt and write a interrupt service routine which writes the complement value to the CCPR1 register. Eg. for 75% duty at 50Hz, the CCPR1 should be changed from 15000 to 20000-15000 = 5000. Next time the interrupt is fired it'll do the opposite, setting the CCPR1 register back to 20000-5000 = 15000.

You'll need to handle cases close to 0% and 100% differently (eg. if <2% or >98% then disable the toggle and set the pin appropriately), but then should give you the PWM signal you need at the CCP1 pin.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't set up the built-in PWM hardware to a frequency as low as 50 Hz at the full processor clock rate.

If that's what you really want to do, just set up a periodic 20 ms interrupt and do the PWM yourself.  You can use timer 1 in one-shot mode, allowing for 16 counter bits instead of the 10 you get with the PWM module.  Remember that while the repetition period is 20 ms, the pulse length only varies from 0 to 2 ms.

Comment: Your opening statement is 100% accurate but could mislead one to think that the PWM cannot be used in making pulses for hobby RC servos. The merits of using TIMER1 and CPP or TIMER2 and PWM have been debated a lot. See:  **CCP PWM vs PWM SW with interrupts** [link](https://www.microchip.com/forums/FindPost/247407) and **PWM using pic16f877a** [link](https://www.microchip.com/forums/FindPost/250582) These threads discuss the benefits and burdens of each method.

Answer (score 1):

@FourZeroFive

This code can control four pulse modulated hobby type servos like the SG90. It is a complicated implementation so you may be unable to see how it works.

This is an example, not a tutorial on how to use the PIC16F690 PWM to control RC hobby servos.

```
/*  
 *  Date: 2018-SEPTEMBER-12
 *  File: main.c 
 *  Target: PIC16F690
 *  MPLAB: 8.92
 *  Compiler: XC8 v1.45
 *  Application: Use PWM to drive two RC servos 
 *  
 *                      PIC16F690
 *              +----------:_:----------+
 *    PWR ->  1 : VDD               VSS : 20 <- GND
 *        <>  2 : RA5       PGD/AN0/RA0 : 19 <> PGD
 *        <>  3 : RA4/AN3   PGC/AN1/RA1 : 18 <> PGC
 *    VPP ->  4 : RA3/VPP       AN2/RA2 : 17 <>
 * SERVO1 <-  5 : RC5/P1A       AN4/RC0 : 16 <>
 * SERVO2 <-  6 : RC4/P1B       AN5/RC1 : 15 <>
 * SERVO3 <-  7 : RC3/P1C       P1D/RC2 : 14 -> SERVO4
 *        <>  8 : RC6               RB4 : 13 <>
 *        <>  9 : RC7           RXD/RB5 : 12 <> RXD
 *    TXD <> 10 : RB7/TXD           RB6 : 11 <>
 *              +-----------------------:
 *                     DIP-20
 *  
 *  Use ECCP in PWM mode with pulse steering to one of four outputs
 */

#pragma config FOSC = INTRCIO, WDTE = OFF, PWRTE = OFF, MCLRE = ON, CP = OFF, CPD = OFF, BOREN = OFF, IESO = OFF, FCMEN = OFF

#include <xc.h>

/* Helper macros */
#define clear_bit( reg, bitNumb )   ((reg) &= ~(1 << (bitNumb)))
#define set_bit( reg, bitNumb )     ((reg) |= (1 << (bitNumb)))
#define test_bit( reg, bitNumb )    ((reg) & (1 << (bitNumb)))
#define clear_wdt() CLRWDT()
#define nop() NOP()

/*  HITECH PICC-Lite specific notes:
 *  
 *  To get the constants to be computed correctly by
 *  the compiler we specify all constants to be 
 *  UNSIGNED LONG. To do this we appended "ul" to the
 *  constants used in these expressions.
 *  
 *  HITECH PICC has a "feature" that does not honor
 *  an explicit type cast of these kinds of constant
 *  expressions.
 */  

/*  
 *  These defines are used to configure this application for your needs.
 *  
 *  TMR2_PRESCALE
 *  PWM_MAX
 *  FOSC
 *  NUMBER_OF_SERVOS
 *  
 *  The default values are tuned for a 4MHz crystal and four servos.
 *  
 *  After servo has completed their pulse we need to take one
 *  PWM period to update the servo multiplexer.
 *  
 *  You need to make sure that time period for updating all the servos
 *  pulse an extra PWM period for each servo is less than 20 milliseconds.
 *  
 *  Making PWM_MAX smaller will make the extra PWM period for each servo shorter.
 *  The trade-off is that we get interrupted more often to service TMR2.
 *  
 */  

/*  PWM_MAX must be >= 1 and <= 255.
 *  small values (< 100) will cause the TMR2 interrupt
 *  to occur so often they are kind of useless.
 */  
#define TMR2_PRESCALE 1
#define PWM_MAX (250ul)
#define FOSC 4000000ul
#define NUMBER_OF_SERVOS 4    
#define TOSC_ns (1000000000ul / FOSC)
#define PWM_PERIOD_us ((TOSC_ns * 4ul * TMR2_PRESCALE * PWM_MAX) / 1000ul)

/*  The update rate for our servos is 22.222 milliseconds. (45Hz)
 *  So this sets the number of PWM ticks in 22,222 microseconds
 *  SERVO_UPDATE_IN_PWM_PERIODS must be <= 65535 to fit into an unsigned int.
 */  
#define SERVO_UPDATE_IN_PWM_PERIODS ((22222ul + (PWM_PERIOD_us / 2)) / PWM_PERIOD_us)

/*  Position min and max are 16-bit unsigned values
 *  
 *  Define the limits for a particular servo
 *  The servo rotates to the "left" limit for a pulse of 0.800 milliseconds.
 * The servo rotates to the "right" limit for a pulse of 2.200 milliseconds.
 */  
#define POSITION_MIN ((800ul  * (PWM_MAX * 4ul)) / PWM_PERIOD_us)
#define POSITION_MAX ((2200ul * (PWM_MAX * 4ul)) / PWM_PERIOD_us)

/*  Timer 2 interrupt handler 
 *  
 *  This handler updates PWM one and PWM two
 *  for a typical pulse output to control a
 *  common analog model radio control servo
 *  
 *  This example code uses a T2 prescaler of 1:1
 *  and a PWM_MAX of 250. This means that half of
 *  the available clock cycles are used just for
 *  Timer 2 interrupt service.
 *  
 *  As the value for PWM_MAX gets closer to the 
 *  worst case time a larger portion of real time
 *  is used just to deal with the Timer 2 interrupt.
 *  
 *  As the value for PWM_MAX gets closer to the 
 *  best case time the ISR will fail and all of 
 *  real time is spent thrashing in the ISR.
 *  
 */  

unsigned int servo_bank[NUMBER_OF_SERVOS];

unsigned int update_tick_count;
bit servo_updated;
bit servo_bank_output_complete;
bit servo_select_next;

unsigned char servo_select;

static unsigned char T2_handler(void)
{   
 static unsigned int temp_period_one;

 if (TMR2IE)   /* test if T2 interrupt is enabled */
 {  
   if (TMR2IF) /* test if T2 interrupt is asserted */
   {
     TMR2IF = 0;  /* reset T2 assertion */

     if(servo_select_next)
     {
       servo_select_next = 0;
       if (++servo_select < NUMBER_OF_SERVOS)
       {
         PSTRCON = (PSTRCON & 0xF0) | ((PSTRCON << 1) & 0x0F);
         temp_period_one = servo_bank[servo_select];
       }
     }

     if (servo_bank_output_complete)
     {
       {
         servo_bank_output_complete = 0;
         servo_select_next = 1;
       }
     }

     if (update_tick_count == 0)
     {
       update_tick_count = SERVO_UPDATE_IN_PWM_PERIODS;
       servo_select = 0;
       PSTRCON = 0b00010001;   /* PWM pulse steering P1A is first servo */
       temp_period_one = servo_bank[0];
       servo_updated = 1;
     }
     --update_tick_count;

     DC1B1 = 0;
     DC1B0 = 0;
     if (temp_period_one > (PWM_MAX * 4))
     {
       CCPR1L = PWM_MAX;
       temp_period_one -= (PWM_MAX * 4);
     }
     else
     {

       if (temp_period_one != 0)
       {
         servo_bank_output_complete = 1;
         if (test_bit(temp_period_one,0)) DC1B0 = 1;
         if (test_bit(temp_period_one,1)) DC1B1 = 1;
         temp_period_one >>= 2;
         CCPR1L  = (unsigned char)(temp_period_one);
         temp_period_one = 0;
       }
       else
       {
         CCPR1L  = 0;
       }
     }
     return(1); /* interrupt serviced return value */
   }
 }  
 return(0); /* interrupt not serviced return value */
}   

/* initialize the PWM and interrupt on T2 overflow */
void T2_init(void)
{   
    PR2 = PWM_MAX-1;        /* set PWM period */
    TMR2IE = 0;             /* turn off TMR2 interrupt */
    TRISC &= (0b11000011);  /* make RC2,RC3,RC4,RC5 outputs for PWM */
    PORTC &= (0b11000011);  /* make all PWM outputs low */

#if (TMR2_PRESCALE == 1)
    T2CON = 0b00000000; /* postscaler 1:1 */
                        /* TMR2 off */
                        /* prescaler 1:1 */
#endif
#if (TMR2_PRESCALE == 4)
    T2CON = 0b00000001; /* postscaler 1:1 */
                        /* TMR2 off */
                        /* prescaler 1:4 */
#endif
#if (TMR2_PRESCALE == 16)
    T2CON = 0b00000010; /* postscaler 1:1 */
                        /* TMR2 off */
                        /* prescaler 1:16 */
#endif

    TMR2 = 0;

    CCP1CON = 0b00001100;   /* PWM mode */
    CCPR1L  = 0;
    PSTRCON = 0b00010000;   /* PWM pulse steering no output */

    update_tick_count = 0;
    servo_updated = 0;
    servo_select_next = 0;
    for (servo_select=0; servo_select < NUMBER_OF_SERVOS; ++servo_select)
    {
        servo_bank[servo_select] = POSITION_MAX;
    }

    TMR2ON = 1;   /* turn on TMR2 */
    TMR2IE = 1;   /* turn on TMR2 interrupt */
}   

/*  
 *  Interrupt vector starts here
 */  

static void interrupt isr(void)
{   
    if (T2_handler()) return;
}   

/*  This function is part of the 
 *  test and verification code.
 *  
 *  It uses global variables for
 *  input and output. 
 *  
 *  This is not a good style for C programs but
 *  does build smaller, faster code for a PIC.
 *  
 */  
unsigned int servo_period;
bit dir; 
unsigned int delta;
static void update_position(void)
{
 if (dir)
 { /*  count up */
   if (servo_period >= (unsigned int)(POSITION_MAX))
   {
     servo_period -= delta;
     dir = 0;
   }
   else
   {
     servo_period += delta;
   }
 }
 else
 { /*  count down */
   if (servo_period <= (unsigned int)(POSITION_MIN))
   {
     servo_period += delta;
     dir = 1;
   }
   else
   {
     servo_period -= delta;
   }
 }
}

void main (void)
{
    unsigned int servo_one;
    unsigned int servo_two;
    static bit servo_dir_one;
    static bit servo_dir_two;

    OSCCON = 0b01100000;  /*  Select 4MHz internal oscillator */
    /*  disable all interrupt sources */
    INTCON = 0x00;
    ADCON0 = 0x00;  /*  turn off ADC module */
    ANSEL  = 0;     /*  set GPIOs for digital I/O */
    ANSELH = 0;
    PIE1 = 0x00;
    PIE2 = 0x00;

    OPTION_REG = 0b11011110;  /*  Weak pull ups disabled */
                          /*  Interrupt on rising edge of RB0/INT pin */
                          /*  T0 internal clock source */
                          /*  T0 clock edge high-to-low */
                          /*  Prescaler assigned to WDT */
                          /*  Prescale 1:64 for WDT */


    /*  initialize my interrupt handlers */
    T2_init();

    /*  turn on the interrupt system */
    PEIE = 1;
    GIE  = 1;

/*  This is a simple servo movement test
 *  that runs two servos up and down at
 *  different rates.
 *  
 *  Servo one is the first servo in the update sequence.
 *  Servo two is the second servo in the update sequence.
 *  
 *  The cycle rates are:
 *    for servo one is about 1.66 seconds.
 *    for servo two is about 4.28 seconds.
 */  
#define DELTA_ONE ((POSITION_MAX - POSITION_MIN) / 83ul)
#define DELTA_TWO ((POSITION_MAX - POSITION_MIN) / 214ul)

    servo_one = POSITION_MAX;
    servo_two = POSITION_MIN;
    servo_dir_one  = 0; /*  set servo one to count down to start */
    servo_dir_two  = 1; /*  set servo two to count up to start */

    while(1)
    {
      if (servo_updated)
      {
        clear_wdt();
        /*  start critical section. */
        /*  do not allow PWM interrupts */
        /*  while updating servo position array. */
        TMR2IE = 0;
        servo_bank[0] = servo_one;
        servo_bank[1] = servo_two;
        TMR2IE = 1;
        /*  end critical section. */

        servo_updated = 0;

        servo_period = servo_one;
        dir = servo_dir_one;
        delta = DELTA_ONE;
        update_position();
        servo_one = servo_period;
        servo_dir_one = dir;

        servo_period = servo_two;
        dir = servo_dir_two;
        delta = DELTA_TWO;
        update_position();
        servo_two = servo_period;
        servo_dir_two = dir;

      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply can use a timer with an interrupt.

Set the timer so that your interrupt is called in a convenient interval, let's say 100Us.

The interrupt may look like this

```
#define TIMING 200
int ratio=50; // %
void interrupt()
{
    // reset interrupt flag

   static unsigned int timing100Us=0; // or long 
   timing100Us++;

   if (timingMs == ((unsigned long)(TIMING * ratio))/100)) { // be careful of not overflowing
       // toggle pin up
   }
   else if (timingMs == TIMING) {
        // toggle pin down
        timingMs=0;
   } 
}
```

var is declared as a static inside the function, you can also declare it outside as a global variable but I find it cleaner this way.

Code is not tested but it shows the conecpt.